# How can I make an object property to return an object such as document.body?

Tags: javascript, oop

W3school definition:

> The body property sets or returns a document's  element.

```
Const docObj = {
    property1 : value1
    property2 : value2
    bodyProperty : //what do I write here to return bodyElementObject?

    // Here I can make a method
    bodyMethod : function(){
          return bodyElementObject;
    }
 };
```

I can write `docObj.bodyMethod()` to execute the return statement.

But for `docObj.bodyProperty` I'm not sure how?

Comment: Do you know about setters and getters? That allows you to make a property call a function to get the value.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 1):

```
const docObj = {
    property1: value1,
    property2: value2,
    get bodyProperty() {
        return document.body;
    }
};
```